# Python multiprocessing: calling pool.map within a function

Tags: python, windows, function, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to use the `mutltiprocessing` package to use multiple CPUs within a function. When I run a toy example outside of a function it runs in a quarter of a second with no problems (see below).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

start = time.clock()

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=7) as pool:     
        result = pool.map(f, range(1000))



print(time.clock() - start)
```

However, when I adapt the same code into a function (see below), it prints `True` to indicate that `__name__ == '__main__'`, but then it runs forever and never returns a result. I am running Python 3.3 on Windows 7.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

start = time.clock()

def f(x):
    return x*x

def testfunc(r):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(True)
        with Pool(processes=7) as pool:     
            result = pool.map(f, range(r))

    return result

result = testfunc(1000)
print(time.clock() - start)
```

Comment: Try putting the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block outside the function, around the call to `testfunc`.

Comment: In all of the three code snippets mentioned (2 above, 1 in answer), the usage of "with" gives an error. It is the ``AttributeError: __exit__``. I cannot even get the first example to run... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `if __name__ == '__main__'` in wrong place.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

start = time.clock()

def f(x):
    return x*x

def testfunc(r):
    print(True)
    with Pool(processes=7) as pool:     
        result = pool.map(f, range(r))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = testfunc(1000)
    print(time.clock() - start)
```

According to [`multiprocessing - Programming guidelines`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming):

> *Safe importing of main module*
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python
>   interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a
>   new process).
>
> ... one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using if
>   __name__ == '__main__': as follows:

Comment: Have you tested this code? It gives an error saying ``AttributeError: __exit__``

Comment: @PavithranIyer, Which version of python are you using? I tested this with Python 3.3 at the time of posting. I think you're using python 2.x. in which `multiprocessing.Pool` is not a context manager. http://asciinema.org/a/18325

Comment: @PavithranIyer, If you're using Python 2.x, try following: http://pastebin.com/hHKbgaSc (without using context manager)